# c++ My char* array is getting overwritten by the last element added

Tags: c++, pointers, char, c-strings

Hello I am having some trouble with this project. It is suppose to get a sentence from a text file then add it to a char* array[]. I am having trouble with the declaration part in my switch statement. When a word is 3 characters long it replaces all elements in the array with the last element that fits.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int length(const char *a){
    int counter=0;
    while(a[counter]!= NULL){
        counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}

int main() {
    ifstream file;
    file.open("C:\\Users\\casha\\Desktop\\group_project1\\message.txt");

    string line;
    while(!file.eof()){
        getline(file,line);
    }
    const char* message = line.c_str();
    const char *words[9];
    words[0]= line.substr(0,4).c_str();

    int pos = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int wordscounter=0;
    while(pos<=length(message)){
        if(message[pos]== ' ' || message[pos]== NULL){
            switch(counter){
                case 3  :
                    words[wordscounter] = line.substr(pos-    counter,counter).c_str();
                    wordscounter++;
                    break;
                case 4  :
                    words[wordscounter] = line.substr(pos-counter,counter).c_str();
                    wordscounter++;
                    break;
                case 5  :
                     words[wordscounter] = line.substr(pos-counter,counter).c_str();
                    wordscounter++;
                    break;
             }
            counter=0;
            pos++;
        }
        else{
            pos++;
            counter++;
        }
    }

    for(int x=0;x<=8;x++){
        cout << words[x] << endl;
    }
```

Should output like this

```
 The
 quick
 brown
 fox
 jumps
 over
 the
 lazy
 dog
```

But instead produces:

```
dog
jumps
jumps
dog
jumps
lazy
dog
lazy
dog
```

I read something about unallocated memory, I am new to c++ so any help is appreciated 
thanks in advance ! <3

edit --

If I were to manually assign the value to the array like so

```
words[3] = line.substr(3,5).c_str();
```

Then it will print the right output.
So what is the difference between me using this method and my switch statement, its the same assignment???

Comment: "Then it will print the right output ..." - you're skating on *undefined behavior*. Consider `line.substr(3,5).c_str()` Investigate what `substr` returns (spoiler: a `std::string`). Now ask yourself, what happens to that returned `std::string` after that statement. It's a temporary and you make no effort to do anything beyond store a const pointer to its internal string, which becomes dangling on the very next statement. And for the life of me I can't understand why you're tasked with storing `char*` in an array, when `std::string` in a `std::vector` is so much more common in modern C++.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for the response. I think I have an idea of what you are saying. So how would I approach assigning to the char* array without leaving the string dangling past the statement. Haha I do not choose the assignments.

Comment: Manage an entirely different allocation technique. It depends entirely on the conditions of the assignment you were given. As I said, a `std::vector<std::string>` would make short work of this entire thing, but ultimately is likely *not* on the menu of options proffered by your instructor (no `char*` handling required whatsoever).

Comment: @WhozCraig Unfortunately we have really strict rules to follow and I have to utilize the char* array.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you wrote:

> So how would I approach assigning to the `char*` array without leaving the string dangling past the statement.

Change

```
const char *words[9];
```

to

```
std::vector<std::string>> words;
```

Instead of using

```
words[0] = line.substr(0,4).c_str();;
```

use

```
words.push_back(line.substr(0,4));
```

Make similar changes in other places that you are using

```
words[wordscounter] = line.substr(pos-counter,counter).c_str();
```

They can be:

```
words.push_back(line.substr(pos-counter,counter));
```